# ListView.getSelectedItemPosition() return 0 unexpectedly

Tags: android, listview

My `Activity` have a `ListView` that contains `CheckedTextView`. Once an item is clicked, I use `setItemChecked(position, true)` to make the item to be hightlighted.

However, when the activity is just started up, when I touch an item, the item in position 0 also be highlighted. I use `getSelectedItemPosition()` to check, even though it is in touch mode(`isinTouchMode` = true), it return 0 but not -1.

After I scroll the `listView`, it work normally, `getSelectedItemPosition()` return -1 as expected.

Why do this happen? I just want the activity to process in touch mode not input by key.

If it cannot be avoided. Can I correct it? I used `ListView.setSelection(-1)` but it take no effect.

Edit: I somehow solve the problem by delete some redundant code. I want an item at specify position in listView to show on the top of the listView and highlighted when activity start so I used below code:

```
ListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
ListView.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
```

What redundant is (I used the same code twice):

```
ListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
ListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
ListView.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
```

Although I solve the problem, I still want to know what going on behind. Why do the position 0 is selected when I "touch" the listView twice?

Answer (score 0):

Did u set the tag for the checked row?
U have to set the tag for the view in getView().

After that only u can consider the position for the view.
Try by using the that.(ex:yourInflatedView.setTag(position);)

Comment: I tired. It take no effect and it still return 0 but not -1.